# Wp7 dataconnectivity error

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have a table emp2 which contains Empid EmpName Salary

i passed a linq from c in emp where empname=="ss" select c
now i want to show the empid of that empname
but the code is showing error all arround at linq
ERROR ::: Emp2.EmpName' has no supported translation to SQL. at
 countrylist=query.tolist();

private const string ConnectionString = "isostore:/Emp1.sdf";

```
    [Table(Name = "Emp")]
    public class Emp2
    {
        [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true)]
        public int EmpId
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public string EmpName
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public int Salary
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }


    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        using (CountryDataContext context = new CountryDataContext(ConnectionString))
        {

            if (!context.DatabaseExists())
            {

                context.CreateDatabase();

            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Employee table exist already");
            }
        }




    }


    private IList<Emp2> getcountry()
    {
        IList<Emp2> countryList = null;
        using (CountryDataContext context = new CountryDataContext(ConnectionString))
        {
            IQueryable<Emp2> query = from c in context.Emp where c.EmpName=="ss"   select c;
            countryList = query.ToList();
        }

        return countryList;
    }



    public class CountryDataContext : DataContext
    {
        public CountryDataContext(string connectionString)
            : base(connectionString)
        {

        }
        public Table<Emp2> Emp
        {
            get
            {
                return this.GetTable<Emp2>();
            }
        }


    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        IList<Emp2> emp= this.getcountry();

        foreach (Emp2 a in emp)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(a.EmpId.ToString());

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't added an attribute to the `EmpName` property to indicate that it is a column.

Comment: Thanks sir, that particular problem is solved, but now it throws an exception Invalid session id as soon as it reach foreach loop in the button code.. whats i need to do handle this?

Comment: Your exception is due to the fact that you return a query from `getcountry`, but by the time you use the query (`IList<Emp2>`) in the foreach loop in the button handler, the `CountryDataContext` you created has been disposed by the using statement.